# Bad R610 center slots

Tags: hard-drive, dell-poweredge

I bought a Dell R610 from eBay for a personal lab and it appears that the center slots are not working. I have six drives installed which are the same (300GB, 10K, SAS by HP)but the center ones (02 and 03) don't work, they keep blinking amber. I know that is supposed to indicate a bad drive but I switch the drives around with the same slots blinking amber. It doesn't matter if I switch the drives from slots 00, 01, 04, or 05 to 02 or 03. The drive will work on the outer slots just not in the center ones. I've tried searching for it but have not found anything that helps. I have unplugged and reseated the drives, cables and controllers but nothing happens. It doesn't show on the RAID controller.

I have experience with this IT but more on the helpdesk side. I'm trying to install VMware and use the server as a lab. Also note that I did install VMware on the 4 available drives as RAID 0 but I want the other two online and do a RAID 5. No worries on backups. Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

-Alex

Comment: If it's not working then return the device.

Comment: Sounds like the device was sold as-is contact the buyer and/or check the items page to verify that's the case